# Looking for: C/C++ Regex library that supports Named Captures

Tags: c++, regex, winapi

I'm thinking about writing a small application that will help me mass rename files. I currently use an application named 'RegexRenamer', which (I'm assuming) uses the .NET regex engine. The application is fine, but is sort of clunky.

So what I'm looking for is a C/C++ regex library that I can build my custom program off of. Anything that is small and lightweight is preferred (.Net seems heavy).

Thanks.

Comment: Off topic, but have you tried Bulk Rename Utility?

Comment: @CalebD: it's not off topic. could you submit that as a real answer (maybe he'll accept that as the answer and not write his own program).

Comment: Out of Oniguruma and Re2, which one would you recommend?

Comment: @user318811 I've never worked with the API of either library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Perl Compatible Regular Expressions provided by the library [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/)
- [Oniguruma](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/) which is used by Ruby 1.9, PHP 5, and TextMate

Answer (score 9):

[boost regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) supports named captures.

[This chart in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) gives a comparison of several regex engines in a table of features vs library.

Answer (score 1):

Google's open sourced [RE2](http://code.google.com/p/re2/) (PCRE compatible)

Comment: RE2 doesn't support any sort of backreferences in its regular expressions, though it supports named capturing groups if all you care about is getting the data out for use in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Another free application, [Bulk Rename Utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php), already exist with this functionality as well.

Answer (score 0):

Barring some really good reason to choose something else, use the regular expression library in TR1 -- it's been adopted into C++0x almost unchanged, so when REs become a standard part of C++, using the standard one will be a simple matter of changing "std::tr1" to "std::" and re-compiling.

That was based on the Boost regex library, so if you start with them, the port should be pretty easy as well, though I believe Boost includes some features that weren't adopted into the standard.

Comment: TR1 requires support for several different regex syntaxes, but none of those support named captures. (Boost's implementation supports Perl syntax as an *extension*, which does support named capturing groups.)